# Unity 5 Scroll View Jitter in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, unity-game-engine, ios9.1

I am using unity scroll rect in a UI of my game. It is working fine in iOS 8 and previous version. In iOS 9 when I scroll the elements they scroll by jittering.

Anyone knows how this can be fixed?